# For Loop on files makes infinite loop

Tags: sql, batch-file, cmd

I'm stuck on a problem with a for loop into my batch file.
The code below is used to change per example "INSERT" statement in a SQL file to INSERT IGNORE.

```
for %%f in (%folder%\*.sql) do (
   %~dp0\jager.exe -C "%%f" DROP \x23
   %~dp0\jager.exe -C "%%f" INSERT "INSERT IGNORE"
   %~dp0\jager.exe -C "%%f" "CREATE TABLE" "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS"
)
```

So in this loop the jager.exe is a 'Find &  Replace' program but the files are modified and the loop takes it again. 
So i made an infinite loop but that's not what i want.

I tried many things, but for now i have no idea how to avoid that infinite loop.

Can i get the Iterator from the loop ? Or is there any way to make it **NOT** infinite looping ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: <dos>? "_A family of text-based operating systems for IBM PCs and compatibles of the 1980s and 1990s, including MS-DOS. DO NOT USE THIS TAG FOR QUESTIONS ABOUT THE WINDOWS COMMAND PROMPT! Instead, use the [windows], [batch-file], [windows-console], and/or [cmd] tags. For questions about denial-of-service (DoS) attacks, use [denial-of-service]._"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change to:

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b "%folder%\*.sql"') do (
```

The `dir` command gets completely executed, before `for` starts processing it's output, so files created during the process will not be processed.

Answer (score 1):

Output the result to a subfolder, then when you're finished copy everything back to the main folder and delete the subfolder.  Or move the contents of the current folder into a subfolder and iterate through the subfolder from the current folder then when you're finished move everything back.